# Determining if something is an invariant

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck trying to show that this is true.

Let $G$ be a group that acts on a set $X$.  Let $Y$ be any set.  A function $f: X \to Y$ is said to be invariant if given any $x_1,x_2 \in X$ with $x_1, x_2$ on the same orbit, then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Let $G$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}^*$ (Complex numbers under multiplication) and $X=\mathbb{C}$ where $G$ acts on $X$ by multiplication.  Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by given by the rule $f(z)=|z|$.

(a)  Show that this is an invariant.

First, we have to figure out what the orbits are.  I think the orbits in this group action are "small" in the sense that they only contain one element.  So if two elements shared an orbit, they would be the same point.  Hence we get for free that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$.

Comment: How does $G$ acts on $X= \mathbb C$?

Comment: By multiplication.

Comment: So if $x=1\in X$ and $g=\sqrt{-1}\in G$, then $gx\neq x$.

Comment: It might help to think about this action geometrically.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If $g=\sqrt{-1}$, then $g=i$.  So we fix $g$ and we multiply it by everything in $C$.  Then we have for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $gz=ire^{i\theta}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}re^{i\theta}=re^{i\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$.  It seems as if it rotates everything in $\mathbb{C}$.  It would appear to be everything on a ray (I think).

Comment: Hint: orbits are circles.

Comment: Why aren't they rays?

Comment: Why *would* they be rays? If you take a point and rotate it around the origin, you get a circle, not a ray. In point of fact, the trivial orbit (the circle group applied to $1$) is a circle. Basic geometry...

Comment: I'm still not sure how to show this is an invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let $\alpha:(g,z)\in G\times \mathbb{C}\mapsto\alpha(g,z)\in\mathbb{C}$ be the given action (maybe the definition of action you have is different: the action may be something like $\alpha:G\rightarrow Bij(\mathbb{C})=\left\{bijections\ on\ \mathbb{C}\right\}$. In this case, you should read $\alpha(g,z)=\alpha(g)(z)$).

By definition, the action $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha(g,z)=gz$, for every $g\in G$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $G(z)=\left\{\alpha(g,z)=gz:g\in G\right\}$ denote the orbit of an element $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Fix $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

> Let's show that $G(z)=\left\{w\in\mathbb{C}:|w|=|z|\right\}$.

If $w\in G(z)$, then $w=gz$ for some $g\in G$, so $|w|=|gz|=|g||z|=1|z|=|z|$.

On the other hand, if $|w|=|z|$, define $p\in\mathbb{C}$ by
$$p=\begin{cases}{w}/{z}&\text{, if }z\neq 0\\
1&\text{, if }z=0.\end{cases}$$
In both cases, $|p|=1$, so $p\in G$, and $w=pz\in G(z)$.

Now it is easy to show that $f$ is invariant. If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are elements of $\mathbb{C}$ which belong to the same orbit, say $G(w)$, then, by the above assertion,
$f(z_1)=|z_1|=|w|=|z_2|=f(z_2)$. Hence, $f$ is invariant.

Comment: I saw a similar question on this site.  Does it follow from the fact that $f(gz)=f(re^{i(\theta+\phi)})=|r|\cdot 1$ where $e^{i\theta}$ is on the unit circle and $re^{i\phi}$ is any real.

Comment: I meant to say $re^{i\theta}$ is any complex.